# Add ActiveFilterString clause to DevExpress GridView CustomFilterRow

Tags: vb.net, gridview, devexpress, .net-2.0

I have DevExpress `GridView` where I have a datatable as datasource. Now I have a hidden column which is used to filter the view using `CustomFilterRow` event. Now the problem is when  the user puts in any filter it is ignored as `e.Handled` in the `CustomFilterRow` event is set to `True`. What I want is to also filter the view using the user's filter string keeping my filter active, i.e. no matter whatever the filter the user provides it will always add on the filter algorithm I've provided originally in the `CustomFilterRow` event.

```
Private Sub GridView_Dept_CustomRowFilter(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.RowFilterEventArgs) Handles GridView_Dept.CustomRowFilter
    If IsLoadComplete = False Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim view As GridView = CType(sender, GridView)
    Dim dv As DataView = view.DataSource
    If Not IsEqual(dv(e.ListSourceRow).Item("EXUSER"), Me.GridViewUser.GetFocusedRowCellValue("EXUSER")) Then
        e.Visible = False
        e.Handled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

DevExpress - 9.2 .Net - 2.0 VS - 2008

P.S. - I'm not allowed to upgrade to higher versions because of company policy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found out the answer. If I write the `e.Handled =True` as the last line in the event, which always gets executed then the user custom filter is always ignored but if I write the `e.Handled = True` inside my custom condition block then everything is working fine.

So any event which has `e.Handled` property in the event argument object, be careful to set the `e.Handled` property to `True`. You should always make sure that you're setting the `e.Handled` property to `True`only inside the condition which if satisfies overrides the default functionality. Setting the `e.Handled` property to `True` at the end of the function will always override the default functionality, which might not be the desired behavior.